# Error in "within" part of Anova in R

Tags: r, rstudio, anova

Can somebody tell me what´s wrong with this code, i´m completely new to R, and it seems to me, that I did it correctly, but i guess there´s some error in the 
list of the within part.

Thanks in advance.

```
data <- read.table("all_data_aggregated_labeled.dat", header = TRUE)


data$participant  <- factor(data$participant)                            # 


library(ez)
library(schoRsch)


anova_rt <- ezANOVA(data=data, dv = .(rt_mean), wid = .(participant), 
                within = .(dual_task, stimulus_material, set_size, change_magnitude), detailed = TRUE)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "within = .(dual_task, stimulus_material, set_size, change_magnitude),"
```

Output str(data):

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   612 obs. of  11 variables:
$ participant                 : Factor w/ 17 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ dual_task                   : Factor w/ 3 levels "MOTOR","NONE",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ stimulus_material           : Factor w/ 2 levels "Color","Rotation": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
$ set_size                    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Four","Three": 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
$ change_magnitude            : Factor w/ 3 levels "Medium","None",..: 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 ...
$ hit_percentage              : num  0 0.333 0.667 0 0.333 ...
$ miss_percentage             : num  0 0.167 0.333 0 0.5 ...
$ false_alarm_percentage      : num  0 0.5 0 0.333 0.167 ...
$ correct_rejection_percentage: num  1 0 0 0.667 0 ...
$ a_prime                     : num  1 0.375 0.917 0.917 0.667 ...
$ rt_mean                     : num  1836 1808 1824 1704 1912 ...
```

Comment: Can you include the output from `str(data)` please?

Comment: I added it to the main post